# Display different content on my vuetify app drawer based on user roles in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

For example, let's say my app will have 2 user roles, admin & customer. I want the content for my app side drawer to display different content which you can see from the code below:

my @/assets/api/menu.js

```
const Menu = [
    {
        title: 'Home',  //THIS VISIBLE TO ALL USER ROLES
        href: '/home'
    }, 
    {
        title: 'Admin', //VISIBLE TO ADMIN ROLES ONLY
        href: '/admin'
    }, 
    {
        title: 'Admin Setting', //VISIBLE TO ADMIN ROLES ONLY
        href: '/adminsetting'
    }, 
    {
        title: 'Customer', //VISIBLE TO Customer ROLES ONLY
        href: '/customer'
    }, 
    {
        title: 'Customer Profile',  //VISIBLE TO Customer ROLES ONLY
        href: '/customer profile'
    }, 
];

  // reorder menu
  Menu.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.items) {
      item.items.sort((x, y) => {
        let textA = x.name.toUpperCase();
        let textB = y.name.toUpperCase();
        return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
      });
    }
  });
  
  export default Menu;
```

I want whenever user is login, if they're admin, they will see only `/home, /admin, /adminsetting` on the sidebar navbar of their screen. And if they're customer, they will see `/home, /customer, /customerprofile`  on the sidebar navbar of their screen.

Below is my app drawer that will display the menu content.

my App Drawer @/components/AppDrawer.vue

```
            <v-list dense expand>
                <template v-for="(item, i) in menus">
                    <!-- group with subitems -->
                    <v-list-group v-if="item.items" :key="item.name" :group="item.group" :prepend-icon="item.icon"
                        no-action="no-action">
                        <v-list-item slot="activator" ripple="ripple">
                            <v-list-item-content>
                                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                            </v-list-item-content>
                        </v-list-item>
                        <template v-for="(subItem, i) in item.items">
                            <!--sub group-->
                            <v-list-group v-if="subItem.items" :key="subItem.name" :group="subItem.group" sub-group="sub-group">
                                <v-list-item slot="activator" ripple="ripple">
                                    <v-list-item-content>
                                        <v-list-item-title>{{ subItem.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                                    </v-list-item-content>
                                </v-list-item>
                                <v-list-item v-for="(grand, i) in subItem.children" :key="i" :to="grand.href? grand.href : null"
                                             ripple="ripple">

                                    <v-list-item-content>
                                        <v-list-item-title>{{ grand.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                                    </v-list-item-content>
                                </v-list-item>
                            </v-list-group>
                                <!--child item-->
                                <v-list-item v-else :key="i" :to="subItem.href? subItem.href : null"
                                             :disabled="subItem.disabled" :target="subItem.target" ripple="ripple">
                                    <v-list-item-content>
                                        <v-list-item-title><span>{{ subItem.title }}</span></v-list-item-title>
                                    </v-list-item-content>
                                    <v-list-item-action v-if="subItem.action">
                                        <v-icon :class="[subItem.actionClass || 'success--text']">{{ subItem.action }}</v-icon>
                                    </v-list-item-action>
                                </v-list-item>
                        </template>
                    </v-list-group>
                    <v-subheader v-else-if="item.header" :key="i">{{ item.header }}</v-subheader>
                    <v-divider v-else-if="item.divider" :key="i"></v-divider>
                    <v-list-item v-else :to="item.href ? item.href : null" ripple="ripple"
                                 :disabled="item.disabled" :target="item.target" rel="noopener" :key="item.name">
                        <v-list-item-action v-if="item.icon">
                            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                        </v-list-item-action>
                        <v-list-item-content>
                            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                        </v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-action v-if="item.subAction">
                            <v-icon class="success--text">{{ item.subAction }}</v-icon>
                        </v-list-item-action>
                    </v-list-item>
                </template>             
            </v-list>
```

I'm also using firebase in my app but I dont think that firebase is really needed in this (to display certain pages based on user type) but idk. Can it be done in Nuxt only?
Or is there any better way for this?

Comment: Hi, please try to narrow down your issue and share only the relevant parts of your code. Did you tried using a `v-if` to have a conditional to either display an `admin` or a `customer` related content?

Comment: Done edit the question. Will consider using v-if to display certain user types related content. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have an access token saved in cookies/localstorage to understand if user is logged or not, right?

You can simply add an authentication file in your storage and check for the access token.

Then in your menu component pick the getters for authentication, check it, and render the right menu items with conditional rendering `v-if`

```js
export const state = () => ({
  isAdmin: false,
  accessToken: null,
})

export const getters = {
 accessToken(state) {
  return state.accessToken
 },
 isAdmin(state) {
  return state.accessToken && state.accessToken !== '' && yourAdminCondition
 }
}
```